# How To Return Data Validation values with special characters/non alphanumeric Characters in Query formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My formula breaks with cells values input contain those characters `(` `'` `(`.

Here's [The sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8pMhvp7K-uLmxoqHUwIuhzQr5SGBeuWZCCzuV8RUGQ/edit?usp=sharing) (Sheet "Report", Cells `A2`, `B2`, and `A5`).

Non working cell input example (in Sheet "Data", Column `C`):

`Mark (this doesn't work)`

The error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: 
PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "t "" at line 1, column 60. 
Was expecting one of: 
"," ... ")" ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... 
"/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ... "," ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... 
")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... 
")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... ")" ... 
")" ... ")" ... ")" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...
```

Screenshot:

[image: swq]

As you can see, the cells with input with parentheses and apostrophes return an error.

Based on this prior solution

[Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "s "" at line 1, column 2168](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71675118/10789707),

I adapted the formula to this in `A5`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(
        Data!B1:E,"SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "
        &IF(A2="All Regions",""," AND LOWER(B) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")
        &IFS(B2="All Reps","", 
                REGEXMATCH(B2,"(\(|\)|')"),
                " AND LOWER(C) = LOWER('"& 
                SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, "(", "\("), "'", "♦"), ")", "\)")&"') ") ,1),"♦", "'")
```

It is returning only the first cell of the validation range.

No error, but more cells are expected.

Screenshot:

[image: x]

Why isn't it working?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing single quotation marks with three times double quotation marks. It will help to avoid problems with some special characters:

```
=QUERY(
        Data!B1:C,"SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "
        &IF(A2="All Regions",""," AND LOWER(B) = LOWER("""&A2&""") ")
        &IF(B2="All Reps",""," AND LOWER(C) = LOWER("""&B2&""") ") ,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great help! Many thanks. I couldn't see it. I'll check to understand it fully next. Be well!

Comment: It's a tricky topic, but not hard to avoid. Try looking for "escape for special characters" or similar. For example: https://sheetsiq.com/google-sheets/formulas/escape-quotes-in-google-sheets/

Comment: Thanks again! I tend to get tunnel vision with those :) and always forget it! Bookmarked for similar later use cases! This doc is well explained.